# Open File in Android Studio with file in project using Apache POI

Tags: java, android, excel

I have placed an xlsx file named menuA as you may see in the photo below:

[image: menuA.xlsx]

But I fear that I am not accessing it correctly using FileInputStream

```
FileInputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File("menuA.xlsx"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    XSSFWorkbook workbook=null;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //create a sheet object
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //that is for evaluate the cell type
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
```

I have moved from NetBeans to Android Studio, where my code works perfectly in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the same file in the **assets** folder (The place to put static resources for easy access) and access those assets as following

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("menuA.xlsx");
```

EDIT:

Since the library that you are using `FileInputStream`, You can copy the file over to the application's private data storage, which is `getExternalFilesDir(null)`. and access the file from there.

Comment: The thing is Apache requires FileInputStream to read files. FileInputStream does not accept getAssets. I have tried doing so with the following code:

 `InputStream file = context.getAssets().open("menuaa.xlsx");`

But the file still is not read